# Prove a convergent sequence has either a minimum, a maximum or both.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence. Prove $a_n$ has a minimum, a maximum or both.

I am being prepared for a final exam, which is why it is important to me to know that $I$ am correct in $my$ attempt. Of course if I am completely wrong, hints or solution are welcome. Thanks.

$Attempt$: $a_n$ converges to a limit $L\in \Bbb{R}$ as $n\to \infty$. Therefore, for $\epsilon=1$ we get, for large enough $N$ that $\forall n\ge N,$ $|a_n-L|<1$ $\Rightarrow$ $L-1 \le a_n\le L+1$, in particular $a_n\le L+1$. Therefore, for $M=max(a_1,a_2,...,a_N,L+1)$, $a_n\le M$ necessarily. i.e, $a_n$ is upper bounded. The same can be shown with lower bound. If $a_n$ is constant, we are done. Otherwise, the lower and the upper bounds are different. Suppose $a_n$ has no minimum nor maximum, then both lower and upper bound are accumulation point, a contradiction. Therefore $a_n$ has a maximum or a minimum in that case.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Actually, your first proof (i.e. the 3 first line of your *Attempt*) proved every things ! You don't need to look the difference cases after.

Comment: I believe you are right... But I never encountered a claim that says that there actually are min\max so I felt like proving it...

Comment: @idm: No, it doesn't, but the rest of Meitar's proof does. The question is not if $(a_n)$ is bounded from above or below (that means that the $\sup$ or the $\inf$ of the set $\{a_n\ |\ n\in\mathbb N\}$ exists. The question rather is to prove that there is some $n$ such that $a_n=\sup$ or $a_n=\inf$, so $\sup$ or $\inf$ are attained.

Comment: @idm The first three lines do not prove everything. If we let $a_n=\sin n$ then we don't have convergence, but we still have all from sentene two on, i.e., for $\epsilon=1$ we have $|a_n-0|<1$ for all $n$. (And of course $a_n=\sin a_n$ has no max/min)

Comment: I see, sorry, I'm not english, therefore I don't understand all the subtleties.

Comment: It looks really fine to me. Perhaps adding a very short explanation why having to **different** accumulation points is a contradiction would help a little, but I'd give all the points to your answer, @Meitar . +1

Comment: The logic could be, I think, clearer. There is an argument that uses the same basic idea but does not mention accumulation points, and is perhaps shorter.

Comment: I found a little error, the sup\inf are the accumulation points...

Comment: @Meitar they are not necessarily accumulation points (think of a constant sequence) even if in some case they may be, but they are always adherent to the set of values of the sequence, and this the only thing needed.

Comment: That, I concluded assuming the sequence is not constant, knowing the sequence has a supremum and an infimum that are not in the sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)_n$ a real-valued convergent sequence. As you proved, this sequence is bounded, so that $m = \inf\{a_n\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ and $M = \sup\{a_n\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}\}$ do exist in $\mathbf{R}$.

We want to show that there exist an $n\in\mathbf{N}$ such that either $a_n = m$ or $a_n = M$. If $m=M$ everything is clear, so we may suppose $m<M$.

Suppose the contrary : $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}, a_n \not= m$ and $a_n \not= M$, *i.e.* $\forall n\in\mathbf{N}, a_n > m$ and $a_n < M$, by definition of $m$ and $M$. Recall what a sup (resp. inf) $m$ (resp. $M$) of a non empty-set $X$ bounded from above (resp. bounded from below) is. It is the unique $m$ (resp $M$) such that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, there exist an $x\in X$ such that $M-\varepsilon \leq x$ (resp. $x \leq m+\varepsilon$.) Let apply this with $X = \{a_n\;|\;n\in\mathbf{N}\}$. For $n = 0$, there is a $k_0$ (resp $l_0$) such that $M - 2^{-0} \leq u_{k_0} < M$ (resp. $m + 2^{-0} \geq l_{k_0} > m$.) There is now a $k_1$ (resp $l_1$) strictly bigger that $k_0$ (resp $l_0$) such that $\max(M - 2^{-1} , u_{k_0}) < u_{k_1} < M$ (resp. $\min(m + 2^{-1} , u_{l_0}) > u_{l_1} > m$.) (As we know by previous inequalities that the most right hand side term is $< M$ (resp. ($>m$.)

Iterating this process, we are able to construct a strictly increasing sequence $(k_n)_n$ (resp< $(l_n)_n$) such that the sequence $(a_{k_n})_n$ (resp. $(a_{l_n})_n$) is strictly incresasing (resp. decreasing) and such that $\forall n \in\mathbf{N}, a_{k_n} \in ]M-1/2^n, M[$ (resp. $a_{l_n} \in ]m+1/2^n,m[$. Therefore $(a_{k_n})_n$ converges to $m$ and $(a_{l_n})_n$ to $M$, showing that $m=M=\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the limit of $(a_n)_n$, as every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit than the one of the convergent sequence. This is a contradiction, as we supposed that $m<M$. This shows that in any case, there exist an $n\in\mathbf{N}$ such that either $a_n = m$ or $a_n = M$.

As you may remark, you don't really need our two subsequences two be strictly monotonous, so that knowing that $m$ and $M$ are accumulation points of $X$ is not needed. The only thing that is needed is that $m$ and $M$ are adherent to $X$.

Answer (score 3):

We use the notation of the OP. The result is clear if all the $a_k$ are equal to the limit $L$. Thus we can assume that for some $k_0$ we have $a_{k_0}\ne L$. For simplicity let $a_{k_0}=c$. By symmetry we can suppose that $c\gt L$.

By the definition of limit, there is an index $N$ such that $|a_n-L|\lt c-L$ if $n\gt N$. In particular,  $a_n\lt c$ for $n\gt N$.

The (multi)set $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_N\}$ has a maximum $b$, and $b\ge a_k$ for all $k$.