# Problem 102 from Pólya-Szegő book

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, problem-solving

Assume that there exists for the sequence $t_1, t_2, \dots$ a sequence of positive numbers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots$, converging to $0$, for which $$t_{n+1}>t_n-\alpha_n \ \text{for all} \ n\in \mathbb{N}.$$ Then the numbers $t_1,t_2,\dots, $ are everywhere dense between their lowest and highest limit points.

**Solution:** Suppose that $l=\liminf \limits_{n\to \infty} t_n$ and $L=\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty} t_n$.

It easy to check that the case $l=L$ is obvious.  It has three subcases: $l=L=\pm \infty$ and $l=L$ is a real number.

So we suppose that $l<L$ and $l,L\in \mathbb{R}$ (the case when at least one of them is infinity can be proven in the same way just with slight modifications).

So our goal to show that $\{t_n: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is dense in $[l,L]$. It is enough to show its density on an open interval $(l,L)$.

Suppose that $\xi\in (l,L)$ and $\epsilon>0$ be given. Consider $$\delta:=\frac{1}{2}\min \{\xi-l, L-\xi, \epsilon\}>0.$$

Also $\exists N_0$ such that if $n\geq N_0$ then $0<\alpha_n<\delta/2$.

By definition of $l$ and $L$ we can find $N>M>N_0$ such that $|t_M-L|<\frac{\delta}{2}$ and $|t_N-l|<\frac{\delta}{2}$. Then I claim that the following statement is true.

**Statement:** At least one of the $\{t_M,\dots,t_N\}$ belongs to the interval $(\xi-\delta, \xi+\delta)$.

*Proof:* Suppose that is not true. Consider the following set $$\mathcal{C}:=\{i\in \{M\dots,N\}: t_i\geq \xi+\delta\}.$$
We note that $M\in \mathcal{C}$ because $\delta\leq \frac{1}{2}(L-\xi)$.

Then $\exists \max \mathcal{C}=p$. Then $p+1\notin \mathcal{C}$ and hence $t_{p+1}<\xi+\delta$. Since we assumed that none of the elements of $\{t_M,\dots, t_N\}$ belongs to $(\xi-\delta,\xi+\delta)$ then $t_{p+1}<\xi-\delta$. Hence $t_p-t_{p+1}\geq 2\delta$.

Since $p\geq M>N_0$ hence $t_{p+1}-t_p>-\alpha_p>-\delta/2$. Combining these two inequalities we obtain that $\delta/2>t_p-t_{p+1}\geq 2\delta$ which is contradiction.
Since the statement is valid then $\exists k$ such that $|t_k-\xi|<\delta<\epsilon.$

As I told above this proof can be easily adapted if at least one of the $l$ or $L$ are infinite.

The proof seems correct to me but I was wondering is everything alright here?
Thanks a lot for attention!

**EDIT:** Usually when we say that $A$ is dense in $X$ we mean $A$ to be subset of $X$.

But I notice that in this case $\{t_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ may not be subset of $[l,L]$ because some elements of $t_n$ may be outside of $[l,L]$. Can anyone explain it to me, please?

Comment: A am a bit confused. $t_n = n$ and any $\alpha_n$ satisfies the assumption, but $\{ t_n\}$ is no-where dense, right?

Comment: @ArcticChar, Nice remark. If $t_n=n$ then I guess that $l=L=+\infty$, right? So we can say that $t_n$ is dense in $\{+\infty\}$, right? Because any nbhd of $+\infty$ which $(c,+\infty)$ has some element of that sequence.

Comment: @ArcticChar, but what do you think about my edit?